# System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'

Tags: c#, .net, camera

I am working with Astra Pro to get the depth data from the camera on VS2022. In my project, I have 2 classes to process with depth data (DepthBuffer) and color frame (ColorBuffer) and they are inheritances from an abstract parent class (Buffer).

In parent class, I have an abstract method that calculates the depth value:

```
public abstract float GetDepthAt(int x, int y);

depthValue = GetDepthAt(320, 240);

public float DepthValue => depthValue;
```

and define it in Depth class:

```
 public override float GetDepthAt(int x, int y)
 {
     short depth = GetNativeDepthAt(x, y);
     return ((float)depth);
 }
```

However, when I run the code, it got build error. I figured that I didn't define GetDepthAt method in the Color class so I defined it as:

```
public override float GetDepthAt(int x, int y)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

but it threw an exception: System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.' in the Color class. Previously, when I hadn't showed depth data in UI yet, this didn't happen.

I have 2 ImageBox to show depth image and color image. When I run the depth image alone, it's fine but when I run the color mode simultaneously, it threw exception.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you say "fix this", what do you actually want to happen?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough. I want to show the depth image and color image in UI simultaneously without throwing exception. I think the exception appear because of this code line: `throw new NotImplementedException();`. But I don't process depth data in Color class so I don't know how to deal with it :<

Comment: Might be worth reconsidering the design, if depth does not apply to all implementations. Alternatively you could just return 0.

Comment: The code works out fine. Now looking back, my question is pretty stupid. Thanks a lot for helping me :)))))))